# django_filters with LinkWidget need All to clear filter

Tags: django, django-filters

Is it possible to add 'All' link to my filter sets like it is done in admin list filter?
Currently I have this code that works fine, except it does not have 'All' link, to reset filter for certain choices.

In my filters.py

```
class VersionFilter(FilterSet):
    version = AllValuesFilter(widget=widgets.LinkWidget)
    codename = AllValuesFilter(widget=widgets.LinkWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = ['version', 'codename', 'libraries',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VersionFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        libraries = Library.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
        library = ChoiceFilter(
            name = "libraries__name",
            choices = set([(s, s) for s in libraries]),
            widget = widgets.LinkWidget,
        )
        self.filters['libraries'] = library
```

In my views.py

```
class VersionsListViewFilter(FilterView):
    context_object_name = 'versions_list'
    filterset_class = VersionFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the empty choice in the list of choices:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(VersionFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    libraries = Library.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
    CHOICES = [(s, s) for s in libraries]
    CHOICES.insert(0, ('', 'All Libraries'))
    library = ChoiceFilter(
        name = "libraries__name",
        choices = CHOICES,
        widget = widgets.LinkWidget,
    )
    self.filters['libraries'] = library
```

Comment: I get this error
`Exception Type:
TypeError
Exception Value:
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_label'
Exception Location:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py in __init__, line 672`

Comment: Please show me your code how you have used the above solution, use dpaste.com to paste your code and share the link.

Comment: @YorikZiru i have updated the answer to show you how you need to use it. Also if `empty_label` does not work in filtering try setting it to empty string `''`

Comment: strange behaviour. When I add this line `print dir(self.filters['libraries'].field)` before `self.filters['libraries'].extra.update({'empty_label': 'All'})` then exception does not occur, but in UI nothing changes. I have no 'All' link anyway.

Comment: Ok last try.. Try adding `empty_label='All Libraries'` in `ChoiceFilter` constructor see if it works. If not try using `empty_value` param instead.

Comment: That does not work neither with 'empty_label' not with 'empty_value'. 
For ChoiceFilter it is possible to append 'All' as a tuple to list of choices, eg
    field.extra['choices'] = tuple([("", "Any"), ] + list(field.extra['choices']))
'AllValuesFilter' has customised 'field' property, so just appended 
            self.extra['choices'].append(("", "Any"),)

Comment: I knew that solution from the beginning. But as it was third party library i was not sure if that is going to work or not. Anyhow i have updated my answer how you can insert empty choice.